# mysql comparing timestamps with in minutes of each other

Tags: mysql, timestamp

How can i make  comparing time stamps with in a 5 minutes range  in mysql ?

```
2015-01-02 03:04 = 2015-01-02 03:09 matches !
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE time1 >= time2 - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```